# the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 my sql

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I know this question has been asked quite a few times, but unfortunately, I failed to find the solution for this problem. May be there is some trivial thing that I am missing ..

I have exported the database schema from mysql workbench and trying to build the database from it on the linux machine. However when I run the script it throws the error like below:

> ERROR: 1064  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

In addition, I have tried many combinations with quotes and all. below is my part of the exported sql file.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `abcdata` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
USE `abcdata`;
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.17, for Win64 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: abcdata
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   8.0.3-rc-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, 
FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `databoard`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `databoard`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `databoard` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`hwunit_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`brd_board_type` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`brd_manufacturer` varchar(128) DEFAULT '""',
`brd_article_number` varchar(128) DEFAULT '""',
`brd_production_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`brd_delivery_revision` varchar(128) DEFAULT '""',
`brd_present_revision` varchar(128) DEFAULT '""',
`brd_rev_date` varchar(32) DEFAULT '""',
`brd_made_the_last_rev` varchar(128) DEFAULT '""',
`brd_serial_number` varchar(128) DEFAULT '""',
`brd_slot_number` varchar(128) DEFAULT '""',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=51 DEFAULT 
 CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

as specified error is in line 1.

Comment: have you checked if the database has been created? do you see an empty database?

Comment: Maybe the issue is with line ending characters. Try running `dos2unix dump.sql`

You might need to install `dos2unix` first

Comment: I checked it and it seems like empty database is created, as if i remove "IF NOT EXISTS" it says abcdata already exists... I already tried dos2unix and it did not work

Comment: Well, wherever the error is, it ain't here

Comment: What version of MySQL/MariaDB?

Comment: Some reason for having the two characters `""` be the default for your strings?

Comment: MariaDB 5.5.50..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I managed to find the solution, the issue was that I created this sql dump from workbench 6.3 which uses mysqldump.exe and however on the target I had this MariaDb installed which expects different syntax.

So I had to do the additional convert to fit the sql dump with MariaDb syntax. The difference is file before and after the conversion is below:

Before

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `abcdata` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 
*/;
USE `abcdata`;
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.17, for Win64 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: abcdata
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   8.0.3-rc-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, 
FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `databoard`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `databoard`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `databoard` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`hwunit_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`brd_board_type` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`brd_manufacturer` varchar(128) DEFAULT '""',
`brd_article_number` varchar(128) DEFAULT '""',
`brd_production_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`brd_delivery_revision` varchar(128) DEFAULT '""',
`brd_present_revision` varchar(128) DEFAULT '""',
`brd_rev_date` varchar(32) DEFAULT '""',
`brd_made_the_last_rev` varchar(128) DEFAULT '""',
`brd_serial_number` varchar(128) DEFAULT '""',
`brd_slot_number` varchar(128) DEFAULT '""',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=51 DEFAULT 
CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

After

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.17, for Win64 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1    Database: abcdata
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   8.0.3-rc-log
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, 
FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
--
-- Current Database: `abcdata`
--
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `abcdata` /*!40100 DEFAULT 
CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
USE `abcdata`;
--
-- Table structure for table `databoard`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `databoard`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `databoard` (  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
`hwunit_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  `brd_board_type` varchar(128) NOT NULL,  
`brd_manufacturer` varchar(128) DEFAULT '""',  `brd_article_number` 
varchar(128) DEFAULT '""',  `brd_production_date` date DEFAULT NULL,  
`brd_delivery_revision` varchar(128) DEFAULT '""',  `brd_present_revision` 
varchar(128) DEFAULT '""',  `brd_rev_date` varchar(32) DEFAULT '""',  
`brd_made_the_last_rev` varchar(128) DEFAULT '""',  `brd_serial_number` 
 varchar(128) DEFAULT '""',  `brd_slot_number` varchar(128) DEFAULT '""',  
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=51 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Bascially all the statements are converetd into single line instead of multiple lines.